# Read different QStrings with the same previous and the same following word? QString::indexOf

Tags: c++, qt, indexof, qstring

I read two QStrings (ValueOne,ValueTwo) out of a file with (just a basic example)

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QString x = ("yes " 
                 "start ValueOne end" 
                 "no" 
                 "start ValueTwo end");

   //try to read ValueOne
    QString s = "start";
    QString e = "end";
    int start = x.indexOf(s, 0, Qt::CaseInsensitive); 
    int end = x.indexOf(e, Qt::CaseInsensitive); 

    if(start != -1){ 

        QString y = x.mid(start + s.length(), (end - (start + s.length()))); 

        qDebug() << y << (start + s.length()) << (end - (start + s.length()));

    //try to read ValueTwo
    QString s2 = "start";
    QString e2 = "end";
    int start2 = x.indexOf(s2, 0, Qt::CaseInsensitive); 
    int end2 = x.indexOf(e2, Qt::CaseInsensitive); 

    if(start2 != -1){ 

        QString y2 = x.mid(start2 + s.length2(), (end2 - (start2 + s.length2()))); 

        qDebug() << y2 << (start2 + s.length2()) << (end2 - (start2 + s.length2()));
    }
}
```

As you see the source code can't difference between ValueOne and ValueTwo just by "start" and "end", because both QString::mid() methods (which proceed line by line as far as I know) have the same start position and the same length (see http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstring.html#mid ). Therefore I thought if the whole string was one line like

```
QString x = "yes start ValueOne end no start ValueTwo end ";
```

I could difference between the two values with QString s = "yes start" and QString s2 = "no start". So would convert the multiline String into a one line String be a solution and how can I do this? or Is there another maybe better solution?
greetings

Comment: I have no idea what problem you're trying to solve, but if you just want to remove the newline characters from a string x, is it not just "x = x.remove('\n');"? That's literally the very definition of a method on QString, which you really ought to be able to come up with.

Comment: I have no idea what result you want - can you spell that out? And as an aside, you can't concatenate literal strings with the `+` operator.

Comment: @deong: no, I don't want to remove anything. QMichaelBurr: The result I want is QString y = ValueOne and QString y2 = ValueTwo. I edited my question. hope now it is easier to understand.

Comment: The question still doesn't seem to match your previous comment. If you want to "convert a multiline String into a one line string", just remove the '\n' characters like I mentioned. If your actual problem is "extract the text that appears between 'start' and 'end' tags", use a regular expression. There's working code for it in one of the answers below.

Comment: xD, ok now I have understood what you meant :), but in the real case I have no direct QString x , but                              QTextStream Stream (&File); 
      QString x;
      x = Stream.readLine();
      x = x.simplified();                                        Do you know if I can use  "x = x.remove('\n');" on this to create a one line QString?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I already mention in your other question I would prefer [QRegExp](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/qregexp.html). It seems to be more readable.

If your first string is the `2n` value always and your second string is `2n+1` you could use the modulo operator:

```
#include <QDebug>
#include <QString>
#include <QStringList>
#include <QRegExp>

int main()
{
    QString x = ("yes \nstart ValueOne end \nno \nstart ValueTwo end\n"
                "yes \nstart ValueThree end \nno \nstart ValueFour end ");

    QStringList y1;
    QStringList y2;

    // create regular expression
    QRegExp rx("start\\s+(.+)\\s+end\\s+", Qt::CaseInsensitive);

    // don't try to get the largest match (start ValueOne ... ValueFour end)
    // minimal match should be (start ValueOne end)
    rx.setMinimal(true);

    int pos=0;
    int i=0; // counter

    // look for possible matches
    QString match;
    while ((pos=rx.indexIn(x, pos)) != -1) {
        i+=1; // increase counter for every match
        match=rx.cap(1); // get first match in (.+)

        // use modulo to distinguish between y1/y2    
        if (i % 2) {
            y1 << match;
        } else {
            y2 << match;
        }

        pos+=rx.matchedLength();
    }

    qDebug() << "y1:" << y1;
    qDebug() << "y2:" << y2;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With something similar to the code below you could find all the strings between "start" and "end".
Put the search for "start" and "end" in a loop and use the offset parameter of indexOf to continue searching for new delimiters after the first one.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QString x = ("yes /nstart ValueOne end /nno /nstart ValueTwo end ");

    QString s = "start";
    QString e = "end";

    // Look for all the strings between "start" and "end"    
    for(int offset(0); offset < x.length(); )
    {
        // Search for "start" starts from offset
        int start = x.indexOf(s, offset, Qt::CaseInsensitive); 

        if(start < 0){
            break;
        }

        // Search for "end" starts from the position of "start"
        int end = x.indexOf(e, start, Qt::CaseInsensitive); 
        if(end < 0){
            break;
        }

        // Next search for "start" will start from the current position of "end"
        offset = end;

        QString y = x.mid(start + s.length(), (end - (start + s.length()))); 
        qDebug() << y << (start + s.length()) << (end - (start + s.length()));
    }
}
```

Comment: I am really not sure about this. 1. What exactly does this offset(0) mean? 2. Where do you save the different results for the QString y?

Comment: offset(0) has the same effect as offset=0. For now the strings are just sent to qDebug. The rest is up to you